# Generate webservice soap client from wsdl when server using Windows Integrated Authentication

Tags: java, code-generation, windows-authentication, webservice-client

There is an SAP server that has some webservices I need to use, so I am trying to use wsimport to generate the client stubs.

I don't want to find all the wsdls and schemas that are referenced and modify them to do it locally, as that isn't sustainable, if they service should change.

So, how can I use wsimport to fetch a wsdl and generate the client stubs when the server is using Windows Integrated Authentication, where even the wsdl requires credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found is to just copy the wsdl, and add in the changes to get it to work with wsimport, and save it on the jboss server, since it is unlikely someone will figure out the name of the directory, and only port 8009 is open to the world, even the jboss port is closed.

It isn't the best solution, but it works.